# Declaring mathematical expressions as variables in Postgres SQL functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I was wondering if I could get some help with declaring mathematical expressions as variables in pl/pg sql.

When creating a function the general format is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION [insert function name, input parameters and data type]

RETURNS NUMERIC

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS

$$

  DECLARE
       mathEX NUMERIC;  — example variable

BEGIN

—-mathematical operation—-

RETURN math_example;
END;
$$;
```

My question is if the purpose of my function is to create a mathematical operation but the declared variables are sub mathematical expressions to help build the primary math expression then should I store the “sub math expressions” with the variable under the “DECLARE”section? Or should they be listed first in the “BEGIN” section?

For example,

Should it be

```
DECLARE
  X NUMERIC(8,6) : = Z/36;
```

Or....

```
DECLARE 
   X NUMERIC(8,6);

BEGIN
   X := Z/36;

—- then insert primary math formula—-
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mathematical expression in `DECLARE` section as well as in `BEGIN` section. But any variable can be declared in `DECLARE` section only. You can not declare it after `BEGIN`.

See the example below:

```
create or replace function test( z int)
returns numeric as
$$
declare
x numeric(8,4):=round(z*4.1234567,2);
begin

return x;
end;

$$
language plpgsql
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7b84e5a2ad0e19bcbd3ac5a3868d86b4)

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are equivalent. Choose the one that makes the function easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The formats are very similar, but not the same. There is a difference in error handling on initialization. If the expression is in the Declaration section and an error occurs it **will not** be caught by the Exception section; it is immediate thrown to the calling block or statement. If the same error would occur in the Execution section it will be caught in the Exception section and processed there. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a617872ae2b6e30febf22a2a31e2125).